# Removing URL parameters to reset PHP variable?

Tags: php, url, session

I have a personal website where I want to showcase some downloads I've made. Each download has a description and download link, however I don't want to create an individual page for each item (as in 'item1.php', 'item2.php', etc.) because the format is pretty much "standard." So, I put all the text in a XML file and then use PHP to parse it.

Here's what my XML looks like:

```xml
<txtdb>
  <txt name="index">
    <str key="title">Index</key>
    <str key="metadescription">Personal site</key>

    <str key="navigation">Navigation</key>

    <str key="description"><!CDATA[[<h2>Description</h2>]]></key>
    <str key="download"><!CDATA[[<h2>Download</h2>]]></key>
  </txt>
  <txt name="item1">
    <str key="title">Item 1</key>
    <str key="metadescription">Item 1 is awesome, get it now!</key>

    <str key="description"><!CDATA[[<p>Item 1 is an incredible item that you must get right away!</p>]]></key>
    <str key="download"><!CDATA[[<a href="http://dropbox.com">Here</a>]]></key>
  </txt>
  <!-- ... -->
</txtdb>
```

And here's my index.php:

```php
<?php
$current = 'index';

class TextDatabase()
{
  private $_xdb;
  private $_name;

  public function __construct($xdt)
  {
    $this->_xdb = simplexml_load_file('./incl/txt.xml');
    $this->_name = $xdt;
  }

  public function getString($key, $name = null)
  {
    if (empty($name))
    {
      $name = $this->_name;
    }
    $str = $this->_xdb->xpath(sprintf("//txt[@name='%s']/str[@key='%s']", $name, $key));
    return empty($str[0]) ? null : (string) html_entity_decode($str[0]);
  }
}

session_start();
if (isSet($_GET['name']))
{
  $current = $_GET['name'];
  $_SESSION['name'] = $current;
}
else if (isSet($_SESSION['name']))
{
  $current = $_SESSION['name'];
}
else
{
  $current = 'index';
}

$TxtDb = new TextDatabase($current);

include_once('incl/header.php');
include_once('incl/sidebar.left.php');

if ($current == 'index'):?>
<h2><?php echo $TxtDb->getString('navigation'); ?></h2>
<ul>
  <li><a href="index.php?name=item1"><?php echo $TxtDb->getString('title','item1'); ?></a></li>
  <li><a href="index.php?name=item2"><?php echo $TxtDb->getString('title','item2'); ?></a></li>
  <!-- more items -->
</ul>
<?php else: ?>
<h2><?php echo $TxtDb->getString('description','index'); ?></h2>
<article><?php echo $TxtDb->getString('description'); ?></article>
<h2><?php echo $TxtDb->getString('download','index'); ?></h2>
<article><?php echo $TxtDb->getString('download'); ?></article>
<?php endif;

include_once('incl/sidebar.right.php');
include_once('incl/footer.php');
?>
```

At the moment, it works. If I go to 'index.php' I see a list of my items. Then, when I click one of them I'm sent to 'index.php?name=item*n*.' However, I have one link in the header that points to 'index.php' and when I click it, the page reloads, but I'm not back to the index. In order to return to the index I would have to change the link to point to 'index.php?name=index', but I don't like this. Is there a way to make "index.php" (without parameters) return to the index instead of the current item (which I believe is stored in the PHP session)?

This is my first time working with PHP (I like C# better), so sorry if it's a dumb question. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can not simultaneously keep the behavior where the last active item was stored in the session and used when no item is specified in the query string *and* list all items no item is specified in the query string.  It's just not sanely possible.  Either change the header link that's *intended* to bring you to the index *actually* bring you to the index, or ditch the session behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this problem leads to multiple subquestions about your architecture. For example why do you store the name parameter in the session at all? The sense of doing so usually is to transport data between multiple requests without having to submit it each time again.

As far as I understand it, you want to have *name* not to be present if not submitted as parameter. Your code on the other hand is catching exactly this case by implementing a fallback that takes the missing parameter from the session.

Therefore I would suggest to change the index.php like this:

```
...
session_start();
if (isSet($_GET['name']))
{
  $current = $_GET['name'];
}
else
{
  $current = 'index';
}
...
```

Btw. `unset($_SESSION['name'])` might become handy to delete the item from the session, but I would recommend to rethink the index.php logic instead of making it more complex if the session storage is not needed at all. ;-)

Comment: Thanks, this works! There was no need to store it in the session after all.